# How to save and open SMTP mail in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, sendmail

In my ASP.Net i have to save and open the SMTP mail.I am using SMTP for sending mail.At the same time i have to save it on "Folder" in the application and i want to open it how can i do that?

Comment: Are you trying to save a copy of the message only (subject, data, etc.) or the complete headers?

Comment: thank for the reply...i want to save the entire mail.Like in the same as Outlook save as option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instruct the SMTP client to save to a specific directory. The method below will save the `MailMessage` object as a .eml file.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("[ToEmail]");
msg.From = new MailAddress("[FromEmail");
msg.Subject = "[YourSubject]";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("[YourSmtpHost]");
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\[YourDirectory]";
client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Instead of doing this, is there any other way like saving the mail as .eml or .msg format using filestream.

Comment: @JobyKurian, I would encourage you to try my solution, it **does** save it as a .eml file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply...Also if i do the above coding this will create a file in specified folder.Please let me know how can i open the file?.Its file name is like "2d3df3dc-8a94-478c-81b9-ba07c78a15d2".At the same time i have to send the email also

Comment: @JobyKurian, As far as I know, there is no way to control the file name that the SMTP client uses to save the email. I would suggest reading this tutorial if you need additional control: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/smtpclientext.aspx?display=Print. It will step you through the process of saving an email with a specified file name. The tutorial also provides the code for a nice extension method that will satisfy your needs. I would also encourage you to put a little more time into your questions before posting them. Adding additional detail/requirements in comments is not good for anyone.

Comment: ,ok...I saved the mail.But i am not able to open the message using Outlook.How can i open the file

Comment: @JobyKurian, It sounds like you don't have the correct file handler mappings set up. `.eml` files open in Outlook for me by default.

Comment: Thank you for reply.....Yes there is some problem with my Outlook.Now i identified.Thank You...